# Can PostgreSQL Synchronous Replication between two datacetres — with 65 ms latency — work?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, latency, data-synchronization

If I set up *PostgreSQL Synchronous Replication* between two datacetres (DC1 and DC5),      with etcd cluster across three datacentes (DC1, DC3, and DC5) to avoid split-brain issues,
and the *latency* between DC1 and DC5 is 65 ms (so, 130 ms for both direction), **will the PostgreSQL be able to sustain this latency?**

Comment: It will work, but I'm not sure what you mean by "sustain this latency".  With synchronous replication, a commit to DC1 has to wait until it hears from DC3 and DC5 that the replicated commit succeeded.  That takes time, but when it returns, you know that everyone is up to date.

Comment: I don't see why PostgreSQL would care.  The question should be, will your customers/users put up with it?  No way to answer that with the information given.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has no problem with the network latency, but you will have a problem if you want to execute more than a few data modifications. A busy OLTP application like a web shop will be out of the question.